# phpmailer and fpdf output file

Tags: php, phpmailer, fpdf

i am using phpmailer and fpdf, to create pdf and send it by email.

I am using this lines for output and attach the file.

```
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output('', 'S'); 
... 
$mail->addStringAttachment($pdfdoc, 'my-doc.pdf');
```

I would like to ask if it is possible to attach file without saving it first to disk?

Comment: I think no, but which is the problem? after sent email just unlink attachment no?

Comment: @Simone Rossaini need to hide file, or better not create one in disk

Comment: Creating the file is a must if you want to send it via email, I would create the file in a tmp folder with an obfuscated name, and delete it after sending the email.

Comment: Uh, this is a non-question – you are already creating and attaching the PDF in the correct way without saving it to disk.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking how to do the thing it's already successfully doing!

Comment: @PeterPan2020 no one will see file because on the server because you will delete after sent email (2 second on server?)